# Como mudar URL de links ancoras?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Como alterar aquele sinal de "#" dos links ancorados?

Estou a criar um menu slide em CSS e é horrível este sinal na barra do navegador. Há alguma solução viável? Li a respeito do jQuery Address, mas confesso que não entendi "bulhufas".

Eu estou a usar CSS para mudar o `margin-left` e fazer a `div` em questão aparecer:

```
.panel:target{
    margin-left: 0%;
    background-color: #9887F8;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/subversivo58/s7QhV/1/show/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para mudar o `href` de uma elemento podes fazer assim:

```
elemento.href = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
```

Podes usar também o `.setAttribute` que altera no HTML diretamente:

```
elemento.setAttribute('href', 'http://stackoverflow.com');
```

são maneiras diferentes, [com algumas diferênças](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56774/129).

---

Com jQuery podes fazer com `.attr()` ou `.prop()` seguindo a mesma lógica:

```
$("a").attr("href", "http://www.outra.coisa/");
```

Se o que quer é evitar ter no URL o simbolo `#`, pode usar `href="javascript:void(0)"`. Se não o tiver assim de inicio, pode usar:

```
$("a").attr("href", "javascript:void(0)"); // talvez queira ser mais específco e usar $("#meuSlideShow a")...
```

Usar `#` é um truque antigo e muito útil. Esse `#` ir parar à URL pode ser evitado com o `.preventDefault()` também. Mas parece-me que é a ferramenta errada se o que quer é somente não mostrar o `#`.

**Porém para essa funcionalidade** não precisa de uma ancora, pode funcionar tão bem ou melhor com outro elemento como `<li>`, `<fiv>` ou até `<button>`...

---

Vendo agora o seu HTML e CSS, aqui fica uma nova solução, com jQuery:

```
var elementosMenu = $('.slide_menu .panel');
$('#page a[id^="link-"]').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
    elementosMenu.css('margin-left', '-102%');
    var targetID = this.getAttribute('href').substr(1);
    document.getElementById(targetID).style.marginLeft = '0%';
});
```

### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lx4Vz/

Comment: É verdade, tinha me esquecido completamente do void(0). Perfeito!

Comment: Cara se salvou a pátria thanks man! Resolveu em 100%!

Answer (score 0):

Não há como mudar este símbolo, pois se você mudasse não seria mais uma âncora.

O que você pode fazer é impedir que o evento de click se propague, impedindo que o browser execute a ação padrão do click. É bem simples. Basta usar o `preventDefault()` do jQuery.

Exemplo:

**HTML**

```
<a class="link" href="#">Clique me</a>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(".link").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // Aqui entra o resto do seu código referente ao que quer fazer com o click do usuário
});
```

Comment: O click chama na tela uma div com o atributo id...más mostra na barra do browser o id da div tipo (#galeria). Estou tentando contornar isto. Estou dando uma olhada em [link]https://github.com/tombonner/jurlp que diz fazer isto...más por hora ainda não resolvi :(

Comment: Pode colocar esse código aqui pra eu analisar?

Comment: jsfiddle [link] http://jsfiddle.net/subversivo58/F8LxF/

Comment: Então, temos um problema. Você pode usar o stopPropagation() assim: http://jsfiddle.net/nqV95/1/ Porém, ele irá impedir a execução padrão do elemento <a>, ou seja, a animação não vai funcionar. Você teria que criar essa animacao no JS, e não no CSS. Não creio que seja possível fazer o que você quer desta forma.