# Adicionar atributo a um elemento

Tags: javascript, html, atributos

Em JavaScript podemos adicionar os atributos a determinado elemento com pelo menos duas maneiras:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'meuId';
```

ou

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute('id', 'meuId');
```

Existe alguma diferença em termos de desempenho e/ou compatibilidades entre navegadores, ou qualquer uma das formas serve perfeitamente?

Comment: tem um comparativo no jsperf: http://jsperf.com/setattribute-vs-property-assignment/7. Em termos de desempenho o acesso direto é mais rápido.

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR**

Os elementos HTML têm atributos. Quando representamos esses em JavaScript obtemos objetos com propriedades.

- `.setAttribute` muda no HTML, é mais lento e cego
- `.prop` muda diretamente no objeto do DOM, mais rápido

---

Partindo deste HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="Escreve o teu nome" />
```

Se eu escrever o meu nome nesse input, e fôr buscar o seu valor atual via JavaScript, repara no que obtenho:

```
input.value = 'Sérgio';
input.value;  // dá "Sérgio"
input.getAttribute('value'); // dá "Escreve o teu nome"
```

Ou seja o `.getAttribute` vai buscar a informação ao HTML que é estático, e não ao objeto do DOM que já mudou de valor.

Usar o setAttribute vai mudar o atributo do HTML e tem nalguns casos efeitos diferentes. Por exemplo `input.setAttribute("disabled", false);` vai fazer o contrário do esperado, [vai bloquear o elemento](https://jsfiddle.net/bk40w29d/) enquanto que `input.disabled = false;` [vai fazer o que é esperado.](https://jsfiddle.net/bk40w29d/1/). Isto porque o browser detecta a presença do atributo `disabled` e não lê o valor desse atributo (só a sua presença). Mudando a propriedade `.disabled` muda diretamente o comportamento no elemento.

Um [outro exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/2me45Ljn/) clarifica a diferença entre HTML e a representação no JavaScript do que se passa no DOM:

```
var input = document.querySelector('input');
input.setAttribute('dataA', 'foo');
console.log(1, input.dataA, input.parentNode.innerHTML);
// dá: 1 undefined "<input type="text" value="Escreve o teu nome" dataa="foo">"


input.dataB = 'foo';
console.log(2, input.dataB, input.parentNode.innerHTML);
// dá 2 "foo" "<input type="text" value="Escreve o teu nome" dataa="foo">
```

No primeiro caso o elemento HTML recebe um novo atributo `dataa` e não `dataA` pois o `setAttribute` é *case-insensitive* e o valor "setado" não é retornado por `input.dataA`, nem `input.dataa`.

No segundo caso o `.dataB` é adicionado como nova propriedade do objeto no JavaScript mas não é reproduzido no HTML. Fica somente do lado do JavaScript e não é escrito no HTML.

É boa prática alterar a propriedade diretamente e não misturar os dois no código pois pode gerar bugs bem dificeis de detetar.

---

À parte dos erros que podem ser gerados por `setAttribute` aceder à propriedade do objeto que representa o elemento do DOM [é também mais rápido](http://jsperf.com/prop-vs-setattr).

Comment: gostei dos exemplos `input.getAttribute('value')` e `input.setAttribute("disabled", false)`, realmente é bem bizarro,

Answer (score 2):

O `.setAttribute()` possui problemas com compatibilidade com o IE até a versão 8.

Quanto a desempenho, segundo o teste no [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/setattribute-vs-property-assignment/7), o acesso direto a propriedade é mais rapido.

Opera 28.0.1750.40

```
obj.title = 'This is a test';                 //1,096,233 ops/sec
obj.setAttribute('title', 'This is a test');  //  678,908 ops/sec
obj.custom = 'This is a test';                //  270,003 ops/sec
obj.setAttribute('custom', 'This is a test'); //  146,522 ops/sec
obj.dataset['custom'] = 'This is a test';     //   85,083 ops/sec
```