# Mudar Onclick Javascript não funciona

Tags: javascript

Olá

Eu estou desenvolvendo um script bem simples em javascript, onde ao clicar pela primeira vez no botão, ele chama a função **aluno()** e ao clicar a segunda vez no **mesmo botão** chama a função **professor()**, mas **não** estou conseguindo **alterar** o **conteudo** de **onclick**, onde eu posso estar errando ?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Mudar Botão</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="btnAlunos" value="Alunos" onclick="alunos()" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function aluno() {
                alert("Eu sou um aluno");
            }
            function professor() {
                alert("Agora eu sou professor");
            }
            document.getElementById("btnAlunos").onclick = function() {
                var btnAlunos = document.getElementById("btnAlunos");
                btnAlunos.value = "Professor";
                btnAlunos.onclick = "professor()";
                btnAlunos.id = "btnProfessor";
                aluno();
            };
            document.getElementById("btnProfessor").onclick = function() {
                professor();
            };
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Agradeço desde já

Comment: faz o seguinte , faz as 2 funções bindadas a um id diferente qando vc clika na primeira apos executar a função q vc quer muda o id do item clikado para o id que corresponde a ação da segunda função.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Vou explicar primeiro porque o teu código não funciona:**

Esta linha não funciona pois quando é lida pelo browser o elemento com esse ID ainda não existe:

```
document.getElementById("btnProfessor").onclick = function() {
    professor();
};
```

se vires na consola isso dá até erro pois estás a chamar `.onclick` em cima de `null` que é a resposta de `document.getElementById("btnProfessor")` quando o elemento não é encontrado.

Na verdade não precisas desta linha pois o código funciona com o outro `.onclick` visto que ele está amarrado ao elemento, independentemente do ID ou conteúdo ter sido mudado ou não.

Outra coisa que não funciona como esperas é  `btnAlunos.onclick = "professor()";`, a questão aqui é a diferença entre propriedades e atributos. Já falei sobre isso (e outros aqui) [noutra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56774/129), mas basicamente tens de mudar o atributo no HTML e não na propriedade do elemento DOM. Podes fazer isso assim: `btnAlunos.setAttribute('onclick', "professor()");`. Com estas mudanças o teu código já começa a aproximar-se do que queres (https://jsfiddle.net/8hvx41ke/).

**Porem podias fazer essa funcionalidade assim:**

```
document.getElementById("btnAlunos").onclick = function() {
    var idOriginal = this.id;
    this.value = "Professor";
    this.id = "btnProfessor";
    idOriginal == "btnProfessor" ? professor() : aluno();
};
```

e sem `onclick` no HTML. Repara que dentro dessa função no JavaScript o `this` é o elemento clicado, e podes ter uma pergunta (ternário) a decidir sobre que função chamar. Neste caso ficaria assim:

```js
function aluno() {
    alert("Eu sou um aluno");
}

function professor() {
    alert("Agora eu sou professor");
}
document.getElementById("btnAlunos").onclick = function() {
    var idOriginal = this.id;
    this.value = "Professor";
    this.id = "btnProfessor";
    idOriginal == "btnProfessor" ? professor() : aluno();
};
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btnAlunos" value="Alunos" />
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8hvx41ke/2/

Answer (score 0):

Para o caso que voce quer fazer, isso já resolve e nao precisa trocar a função do click, apenas ceritificar de chamar o metodo que quer:

```js
function aluno()
{
  alert("Eu sou um aluno");
}

function professor()
{
  alert("Agora eu sou professor");
}

document.getElementById("btnAlunos").onclick = function ()
{

  var btnAlunos = document.getElementById("btnAlunos");
  
  if(btnAlunos.value == "Professor")
    {
      professor();
      }
  else    
    {
  aluno();
    }  
  
  btnAlunos.value = "Professor";
};
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Mudar Botão</title>
</head>

<body>

<input type="button" id="btnAlunos" value="Alunos" onclick="alunos()" /> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Todas as sugestões são bem legais, obrigado a todos pelas ajudas.

Answer (score 0):

Em seu modelo você está complicando várias coisas. Além de trabalhar com eventos dinâmicos. Para simplificar, porque não fazer a `function aluno()` alterar o `onclick()` para professor e vice-versa?

Seu exemplo ficaria desta forma:

```js
function aluno()
{
  document.getElementById("btnAlunos").value = 'Professor';
  document.getElementById("btnAlunos").setAttribute('onclick','professor()');
  alert("Eu sou um aluno");
}

function professor()
{
  document.getElementById("btnAlunos").value = 'Aluno';
  document.getElementById("btnAlunos").setAttribute('onclick','aluno()');
  alert("Agora eu sou professor");
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btnAlunos" value="Alunos" onclick="aluno()" />
```

Note que não necessito alterar o `id`. Apenas alterei o `value` para indicar o texto do botão, e altero o `onclick()` em cada função com o [setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).

Comment: Seu código pode ser melhor passando o objeto como parâmetro @Randrade. Digo `<input type="button" id="btnAlunos" value="Alunos" onclick="aluno(this)" />`....

Comment: @Marconi Com certeza ficaria melhor. Mas preferi deixar o mais próximo do código do AP possível, para não complicar muito. Mas obrigado pelo comentário, se o AP entender as mudanças que eu fiz de boa, eu altero um pouco mais.